# When do three cubics form an arithmetic progression?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Are there any solutions to the diophantine equation $x^3+y^3=2z^3$ other than the trivial ones?

What about $x^4+y^4=2z^4$? I think I remember these equations in one of Euler's work, but having trouble finding it.

Any help or reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: See also [Rational solutions of $x^3+y^3=2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500170)

Answer (score 3):

No nontrivial primitive solutions to $x^n + y^n = 2 z^n$ for any $n \ge 3$.
See H. Darmon and L. Merel, [Winding quotients and some variants of Fermat’s
Last Theorem](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/18.Merel/paper.pdf), J. Reine Angew. Math. 490 (1997), 81–100.