# Why can no three cubes be in an arithmetic progression?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

Recently reading some papers motivated by Fermat's more well-known result that no four squares can be in an arithmetic progression (with nonzero common difference!), I saw the claim repeated multiple times that Legendre proved [here](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_hzIVAAAAQAAJ/page/n99/mode/2up) that no three cubes can be arithmetic progression (for example, this is claimed at the beginning of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0227)).

Having tried to scour through that enormous 490 page document which, by modern standards, is rather difficult to navigate and using my reasonable French I have not yet found the proof.

**Can someone either provide a well-written modern exposition as a reference of the proof or give one in an answer?**

The papers I read also claimed that the proof was simpler in the language of elliptic curves but I am not yet familiar with much theory concerning them so I would very much prefer an elementary proof.

Also, just as a pre-emptive comment I do not consider [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313969/when-do-three-cubics-form-an-arithmetic-progression) to be a duplicate since the paper they ended up accepting is about as far away from elementary as can be since it was trying to prove a more general statement.

Comment: I feel like maybe I am missing some important context here, but an arithmetic progression sits on a line, while $x^3$ has a strictly increasing first derivative on positive numbers, so the three cubes can not be all positive. But if we accept negative numbers then we have infinitely many such cubes: $(-n)^3, 0, n^3$.

Comment: @CristianGratie: maybe, but you reasoning also applies to squares, yet there are infinitely many triplets of squares in arithmetic progression (starting with $1,25,49$).

Comment: @CristianGratie: the cubes are all supposed to be positive in the statement of the theorem. I think your comment proves that no three cubes of consecutive integers can be in arithmetic progression but we are potentially considering cubes that are very far apart...

Comment: @Mindlack My bad, I guess I'm tired. Cubes in an arithmetic progression would not sit on a line (if seen on a plot of $x^3$) they would simply be equidistant on the $y$ axis. The question makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: It's equivalent to solving $x^3+y^3=2z^3$, so reference in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2111552/290240) should do. Then it was supposedly solved already by Euler in L. Euler, Algebra 2 (1770), Art. 247; French transl., 2 (1774) 355-360; Opera Omnia I (1) 491

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I believe the answer is fine for my purposes though it's rather unfortunate that there wouldn't be simpler solution (though I guess there is not much reason to suspect there would be). Quite a tough thing to read through! (the book has a chapter 2 with 80+ pages!)

Comment: Thank you regardless @Sil.