# Prove that $2c^3+1$ is never a perfect cube for $c \in \mathbb{N}^*$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am working on proving that the equation:

\begin{align}
a^2-b^3 = 1
\end{align}

where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers has only one solution $(a,b) = (3,2)$.

The equation can be rewritten: 
\begin{align}
(a-1)(a+1) = b^3.
\end{align}
When $b$ is odd, for any prime factor $p$ of $b$, we have that $p$ divides $(a-1)(a+1)$. But $a-1$ and $a+1$ are coprime when $b$ is odd, hence $p$ divides either $a-1$ or $a+1$ but not both. It follows that both $a-1$ and $a+1$ must be perfect cubes. Since there are no pair of perfect cubes with difference 2, it follows that $b$ must be even.

In this case let $b = 2n$ and for ease of reading, let $a = m+1$. The equation can be rewritten:
\begin{align}
m(m+2) = 8n^3.
\end{align}
This implies that $m$ is even, i.e. $m=2k$. The equation becomes:
\begin{align}
k(k+1) = 2n^3.
\end{align}
Depending on wether $k$ or $k+1$ is even, we have:
\begin{align}
q(2q+1) = n^3
\end{align}
when $k=2q$, and 
\begin{align}
(q+1)(2q+1) = n^3
\end{align}
when $k=2q+1$.

When $k = 2q$, since $\text{gcd}(q,2q+1) = 1$, we have that $q$ and $2q+1$ must be perfect cubes using the same reasoning as above. I would like to conclude by proving that there is no positive integer $c$ such that $2c^3+1$ is a perfect cube, hence the question in the title.

Comment: Check here : math.stackexchange.com/questions/133754/diophantine-equations-x3-2y3-1

Comment: See: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61014/solve-x3-1-2y3) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691196/solving-x3-2y3-1-using-cubic-number-field?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495727/does-this-diophantine-cubic-have-solutions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I think I saw something like this in Stewart & Tall. Nagell-Ramanujan, maybe? The proof actually uses a quadratic integer ring, not cubic, go figure.

Comment: Precisely this question is answered by chapter 4 of R. Schoofs book *Catalan's conjecture*.